# Можно ли декомпилировать хранимую процедуру MSSQL?

Tags: sql, windows, .net, sql-server, декомпиляция

Есть dll файл, содержащий код хранимой процедуры. Есть ли возможность декомпилировать его в исходный код на MsSql? Пробовал через dotPeek и похожие инструменты, везде not supported. Есть чувство, что такой трюк реально не прокатит, но хотел бы услышать мнение коммьюнити

Comment: Может, это нативная dll, а не дотнетная?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov возможно так и есть. При дизассемблинге в Ghidra показала три импорта: kernel32.dll, msvcr80.dll и opends60.dll. Не знаете, может быть это чисто для c++?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov судя по всему это была расширенная хранимая процедура по типу такой http://www.coders-library.ru/news-view-193-1-1.html, тоже была функция __GetXpVersion. Пытался это вызввать из кода на C#, указал EntryPoint, получал System.AccessViolationException: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."